# can I use Web apps with Logic-apps

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have asp.net Core Application I have published in Azure I would like to integrate it with Logic app 
and delete the static files from the wwwroot folder 
If there are any other resource are available in azure let me know

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Your question is no fit for SO in its current form. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Logic Apps has an FTP connector that enables you to [Create, monitor, and manage FTP files by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp)

> With Azure Logic Apps and the FTP connector, you can create automated tasks and workflows that create, monitor, send, and receive files through your account on an FTP server, along with other actions, for example:
>
> - Monitor when files are added or changed.
> - Get, create, copy, update, list, and delete files.
> - Get file content and metadata.
> - Extract archives to folders.